# How to fix error setting SSL with certbot using?

Tags: ssl, certbot

I try to set ssl for my php/laravel application under Digital Ocean with Kubuntu 18
as in this articles
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

But I got error trying to use certbot to obtain a free SSL certificate :

```
# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                                                                                                                                                                        
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)                                                                                                                                                                   
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)                                                                                                                                                                   
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)                                                                                                                                                                   
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)                                                                                                                                                                   

# sudo certbot --apache -d products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk -d www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk                                                                              
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log                                                                                                                                                               
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache                                                                                                                                                               
Obtaining a new certificate                                                                                                                                                                                            
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
http-01 challenge for www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
   Type:   None
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
   www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
```

products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk - that is my domain I got on freenom.com and searching  I found a hint that 
I need to add A-record for www subdomain

I tried to add new record as https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0vde.jpg
But trying to suBmit this page I got:

```
• Error occured: Invalid value in dnsrecord
```

What is wrong ? Can new record be issue of my problem ? Or I need to move in other way ?

**UPDATED # 2**
Configuration in appache is :

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/lprods/public    
    ServerName products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
    ServerAlias products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk

    <Directory /var/www/html/lprods/public>
      AllowOverride All
      Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ErrorLog /var/www/html/lprods/storage/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/lprods/storage/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

with line in /etc/hosts

```
138.68.107.5  products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
```

Can it be issue with my problem ?

**UPDATED # 3**
I made some more review and found next :

IP of my server is 138.68.107.4 and under ssh I enter the console of OS as

```
ssh root@138.68.107.4
```

But in my /etc/hosts file I had next lines pointing to some other hosts on this server:

```
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
138.68.107.4  box.example.com box

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

138.68.107.4  votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
138.68.107.5  products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
138.68.107.6  csvp.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
...
```

I modified 3 last lines as :

```
138.68.107.4  votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
138.68.107.4  products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
138.68.107.4  csvp.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
```

But I still not sure is that is valid value, as I have next error again:

```
# sudo certbot --apache -d products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk -d www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk 
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log 
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache 
Obtaining a new certificate 
Performing the following challenges: 
http-01 challenge for products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk 
http-01 challenge for www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk 
Waiting for verification... 
Cleaning up challenges 
Failed authorization procedure. www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up 
A for www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk 

IMPORTANT NOTES: 
 - The following errors were reported by the server: 

   Domain: www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk 
   Type:   None 
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for 
   www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
```

can reason of this error be in wrong IP in /etc/hosts or some other issue ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please look at UPDATED # 2

Comment: The one thing i found out is you install laravel on your Digitial ocean IP but the IP is not pointing to your domain that's why the DNS issue is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!
Looks like you catch the point!
Please look at UPDATED # 3

Comment: can you please check A Records of the domain also @ point of your domain ?

Comment: the solution is maybe You don’t have an A record for your www version of the domain. please add into your control panel

Comment: extended my answer. not only telling what is wrong, but "how to fix it" (as the title reads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain `www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk` does not resolve:

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk

[image]

So it's not a server configuration issue, you simply have to add the `www.products-catalog` subdomain record in you DNS manager,

or remove this: `-d www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk` from the certbot command

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but that is what i wrote in my 1st post : 

I tried to add new record as https://imgur.com/a/ijFxlzN But trying to suBmit this page I got:
• Error occured: Invalid value in dnsrecord
Looks like that is source of my errors. What is wrong in my parameters when I tried to add new in dnsrecord ?

Comment: if you create an `A` record, you must put the ip. If you want to put the hostname alias, you need to create a `CNAME` instead

Comment: Thank you, I installed certificates and got message:
Your cert will expire on 2019-03-20. To obtain a new or tweaked
   version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot again
   with the "certonly" option. To non-interactively renew *all* of
   your certificates, run "certbot renew"
 The period of certificates seems not too long. What expectes my cite at 2019-03-20 and after?
 Which steps have I to take not to have problems with certificates period expired ?

Comment: you can add `certbot renew && /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` in the crontab every week to renew the certs and reload apache. They will get renewed if there are less than 20 days to the expiration

Answer (score 1):

`certbot` complains about:

```
DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
```

a) the local `/etc/hosts` file is not the public `DNS` zone file ...just add the domain name; because virtual host is being told apart by HTTP host headers: `138.68.107.4 nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk`
when using a `DNS` zone file, one does not have to add them into there, alike on the `localhost.`

b) then either use the `certbot` command without the non-existent `www` virtual host:

```
sudo certbot --apache -d products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
```

**or** fix `DNS` and virtual host, in order to serve the `www` virtual host; then they should work for both. an `A` "address" record is being expected; but a `CNAME` "common name" record is being provided. to fix this you just have to change the type from `CNAME` to `A` and wait until it had been distributed.

see for yourself: [non-www](http://products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/) and [www](http://www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/). `HTTPS` also does not respond, at all.

c) and to fix the virtual host configuration, you have to add the proper `ServerAlias`:

```
ServerName products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
ServerAlias www.products-catalog.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run `certbot` with `--manual certonly` then run with `--apache` option it will "reinstall" the cert to your Apache server.

Run :

```
sudo certbot --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory 
    -d *.domain.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns-01 certonly
```

You then add DNS TXT record and click Continue on the `certbot` instruction.
Once complete you can run a simple `--apache install` like this.

```
sudo certbot --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory  
    -d *.domain.com --apache
```

This will ask to reinstall cert and you can just select that.